# using cplex 12.7.1 academic version, the error information is Garbled

Tags: cplex, opl

I am using the cplex 12.7.1 version for a simple linear program.
I think I am right in the coding. However, I get the error information in a messy character, they are shown as follows:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please read how to make a [mcve], so that others can reproduce your errors and help you solve this problem

Comment: Can you see the engine log as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/gsoplide/topics/opl_ide_gs_tut_output_tabs.html#gsoplide.uss_ide_gettingstarted.1044796__gsoplide.uss_ide_gettingstarted.1061456)? If so, please edit your question to include it (as text, not an image).

Comment: I can not see the engine log because it is empty. I solve the simple linear program as an initial example to use the cplex version. The coding is shown as follows:                                                                  dvar float+ x [1..3];
int b[1..3]=[1,2,3];
int c[1..3]=[-1,1,1];
int d[1..3]=[1,-3,1];
minimize  b[1] * x[1] +b[2] * x[2]+b[3] * x[3];
subject to{
x[1]<=40;
x[1]>=0;
x[2]>=0;
x[3]>=0;
c[1] * x[1] + c[2] * x[2]+c[3] * x[3]<=20;
d[1] * x[1] + d[2] * x[2]+d[3] * x[3]<=30;
};